# Error in using Google Play Services

Tags: android, c++, qt, admob, qml

I'm trying use AdMob for motezation.
I've updated android sdk. After that this error in log appears

```
   BUILD FAILED
    C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: 
    Invalid file: C:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\build.xml
        ******
00:49:12: The process "C:\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
        Error while building/deploying project AdMobQtSample (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
        When executing step 'Deploy to Android device'
```

It worked before upgrade, and there's no file build.xml in google-play-services_lib folder.

Comment: what is the version of android sdk and android tool that you have?

Comment: @Tony My version of android SDK is 23.02 and target is API 19, Android buil-tool is 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution in the this page
https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/GettingStartedNativeClient

Problem was that i don't have build.xml file google-play-services_lib folder, to create that file you need Go to $SDK_HOME/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib and run android update project --path . --target android-20. (Change the target as needed.)

Comment: I had to run the command in _<project_folder>/libs/google-play-services_lib_.